# How to add code on app force closing android

Tags: android

i am trying to determine if the user is online or offline in my app using stored database,the issue is when the app is force stopped by the mobile user,the user still in the database online,how can i add a code to makes user offline in database on app force closing,the "onDestroy()" method doesn't meets what i want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  A force close is a terminal event.  The OS literally stops your code from operating.  If you really need this online/offline functionality, implement a timed ping system.

Comment: Not to mention it's the whole point of force closing an app. What if the app isn't responding, or the code you want to run on force close causes the app to hang? It defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: Terminal event is a confusing statement.